# Sitecore user profile Custom Properties not persistent - Sitecore XP-10.0.0 (Initial Release)

Tags: federated-authentication, sso

We are currently using Sitecore 10.0.0 version .

We have a Federated authentication module for user SSO. In our authentication module, we set claims after successful login and send that information to Sitecore end.

In Sitecore, we have a custom processor to check the claims & assign them to virtual Sitecore user. Then we sign-in virtual user.

Authentication module is sending claims properly but when we try to read them in Sitecore processor, we get null value.

Kindly provide suggestions on how to fix this issue for **our version**.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you confirming that the correct claims are being sent? There is a tool called "Si snitch" which shows exactly what claims are being sent. Please see this link where it has been modified for sitecore 10.0 https://www.kayee.nl/2020/11/05/sitecore-si-snitch-upgrade-to-support-versions-sitecore-9-3-sitecore-10-0-0/

Comment: We have control over Sitecore solution and Authentication module. So we debugged the operation in local. While debugging, we could see the claims added to ClaimsPrincipal correctly and that status of the request made from Sitecore end also gets Status Code as "OK".

But issue happens when we get to Sitecore end and try to read those claims.

Comment: please try using the sisnitch, if that shows as null claims then there is issue with the authentication module

Comment: Sure. Thank you. Will check .